# Meaning of "two fingers on the screwdriver tight"

Tags: meaning

I have a technical manual which contains this this sentential:

> When tightening the screws, the first cycle is to get the screws to
>   apply minimum pressure on the cover. The second cycle is to snug the
>   screw (two fingers on the screwdriver tight).

What does "two fingers on the screwdriver tight" means in this context?

Comment: I would interpret that to mean that you are using your fingertips on the screwdriver shaft to turn it, meaning that you cannot get the screw exceptionally tight.  This is consistent with "snugging" the screw.  (Presumably a third round of tightening gets the screws tight, using your full hand to grip the screwdriver.)

Comment: It describes the degree of torque  appropriate. Not full strength. Certainly not ham-fisted but a little more than a watch-maker might use.

Comment: It means *as tight as you can get it if you only gripped the screwdriver with two fingers*. Thus, it is tighter than in the first cycle, where minimal pressure is applied, but not as tight as you could possibly make it.

Comment: And by “two fingers” I’d take that to mean “two fingers and a thumb”

Comment: This is evidently written by somebody who is not competent in English. What they meant is anybody's guess.

Comment: This is one of the nonce (from [lack of] Google returns) multi-hyphenated compound modifiers that have been discussed here before. Normally, hyphens are used to show the compound premodifier (which some would label an adverb, but I'd call a secondary modifier) clearly: two-fingers-on-the-screwdriver tight (cf finger-lickin' good). The only problem I have with understanding it is _whose two fingers_?

Comment: "Two fingers" is the measure of an alcoholic beverage, meaning filling the glass up to the level of the width of two fingers.  A screwdriver is a drink made from orange juice and vodka, and "tight" means intoxicated.  Could this mean that you shouldn't drink more than that amount of a vodka cocktail before reading the mechnical tanual, er, tuchnical menual.  Bartender!  I'll have another, and see what the mods in the back are drinking.

Comment: @HotLicks more likely, the instructions are intended to prevent the screws from being over-tightened, and there is no third round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common expression in construction and is used as a means of giving an estimate of how much torque is expected. It means to tighten the screw as firmly as possible using just your thumb and forefinger to apply torque to the screwdriver. In the context you've given, it sounds like this is to ensure the cover is firmly seated.

Do not use your full grip and involve your entire wrist and forearm when you torque, or you will overtighten. Using a wrench or other means of levering the screwdriver will certainly overtighten the screw. If you overtighten, you could strip the screws, deform the cover, or put excessive tension on delicate parts.

It's given as an estimate because you don't need to be particularly precise or else you'd have an actual torque tolerance and be expected to use a torque screwdriver/wrench to measure.

Comment: I haven't seen this spelt-out use but certainly *finger tight*, *two-finger tight* and *hand tight* are all used as imprecise torque specifications.